# Sharepoint List Column Validation: If certain value in one Column, other Column must not be empty

Tags: validation, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have a problem with the column validation in a sharepoint-list.
I want to force the user to fill column2  if a certain value is chosen in column1 (dropdown). Otherwise it coulmn2 should be left blank.
So far I tried:

```html
= IF([column1]="xxx";LEN([column2]>0;LEN([column2]=0))
```

any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula below to achieve it.

```
=IF([column1]="xxx",IF(LEN([column2])>0,TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```